How to accept clicks in iframe but ignore scrolling from parent page
I've embedded multiple iframes in my webpage. When scrolling on the parent page, the scrolling stops and begins to be forwarded to the iframe once the mouse cursor is over it. I know that I can disable pointer events on the iframe using pointer-events: none, but I need the iframe to allow clicks while ignoring scrolling.
I have control over both the parent page and the iframe content. Is there any solution to this how to address this using HTML attributes on the iframe, CSS, or JavaScript?

I've implemented a method to solve this by capturing the "wheel" event in the iframe, then using postMessage() to pass that to the parent window, which subsequently calls scrollBy() with the value. From my testing, this should also capture the scroll events from a trackpad on a laptop. If there are other events you are trying to capture, it should be possible to include them, also.


window.addEventListener("message", function(event){
    window.scrollBy(0, event.data);
});
body {height: 5000px; background-color: pink; color: black; font-weight: bold; font-family: sans-serif;}
iframe { width: 400px; height: 200px; border: 2px solid black; }
<p>This parent window has a <code>"message"</code> event listener, and is calling <code>window.scrollBy(0, event.data)</code> with data from the iframe.</p>
<iframe src="https://leodillon.com/resources/stackoverflow/iframe-scroll-passthru/iframe.html"></iframe>



I've hosted the iframe.html remotely as I'm not sure there's any other way to post a working code snippet here. It contains the javscript:
window.addEventListener("wheel", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    window.parent.postMessage(event.deltaY, "*");
}, {passive: false});

When I tested on a trackpad/laptop, the scrolling is actually very smooth as I guess it fires lots of small events. With a mouse wheel, as that usually works in a "jump" for each click of the wheel, it will scroll in steps. These are normally smoothed by the browser when handling wheel input directly, however with this method I believe you'd have to implement the smooth scroll yourself if it was desired. But it's not that janky, as it still scrolls at the normal overall speed that you would expect!
Note that passive: false is set in the event listener, too; you might think this is the default, but it is NOT for "wheel" and a couple of other events, specifically!
If you are otherwise using messaging in your application, you'll of course need to wrap this up as a specific message type to be processed in this way.

That absolutely worked, and I like the situation. Thanks!

You can do somthing like this :
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<title>Parent Page</title>
<style>

  .iframe-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 300px; 
    overflow: hidden;
  }
  .iframe-container iframe {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: none;
  }
</style>
</head>
<body>

<!-- Parent Page Content -->
<div class="iframe-container">
  <iframe src="iframe.html" id="iframe"></iframe>
</div>

<script>
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var iframe = document.getElementById('iframe');

  // Event listener for scrolling on the parent page
  window.addEventListener('scroll', function(event) {
    // Check if the mouse is over the iframe
    if (!isMouseOverIframe(event.clientX, event.clientY)) {
      // Allow scrolling on the parent page
      event.stopPropagation();
    }
  });

  // Function to check if the mouse is over the iframe
  function isMouseOverIframe(x, y) {
    var rect = iframe.getBoundingClientRect();
    return (
      x >= rect.left &&
      x <= rect.right &&
      y >= rect.top &&
      y <= rect.bottom
    );
  }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>


Thank you! This is similar to what I have tried before. I am currently on a trackpad and no success. I also made the event listener passive, still I can scroll. Currently debugging, otherwise any idea what might be causing the scroll to still go through?

The iframe element has a scrolling attribute which can be set to no. Here is an example:


<iframe src="https://www.bing.com/search?q=how+to+hide+scroll+bar+of+iframe&cvid=fdd706f4c38342ba9e208ec7334402db&gs_lcrp=EgZjaHJvbWUqBggAEEUYOzIGCAAQRRg7MgYIARBFGDsyBggCEEUYOTIGCAMQRRg7MgYIBBAAGEAyBggFEAAYQDIGCAYQRRg8MgYIBxBFGDwyBggIEEUYPNIBCDE4NzNqMGo0qAIAsAIA&FORM=ANAB01&PC=NMTS" scrolling="no" height="500px" width="500px"></iframe>



Just make sure to specify height and width using the iframe attributes to prevent any css messups.
P.S this question has already been answered in this post.

Thanks a lot! It looked super promising, unfortunately its deprecated and therefore I can't use it

No problem! Also although the W3C Validator reports the scrolling="no" attribute as obsolete and recommends using CSS instead, this is still the one of only 2 methods that can help you disable scrolling on most browsers. The other solution is to put style="overflow: hidden;" as an iframe element attribute.

If it is acceptable that users have to click inside an iframe before being able to scroll it, the following snippet may help you:
Each iframe is covered with a div of equal height and width, this shields the iframe from the mousewheel events. The click event handlers set individual iframe-div pairs to scrollable: by giving the covering div height 0, this allows the mousewheel events to reach the iframe.
A pair loses its scrollable when a click happens outside of it.
The background-color rule gives a visual indication whether an iframe is currently covered and hence not scrollable.


document.querySelectorAll("div.iframe").forEach(function(div) {
  div.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    div.classList.add("scrollable");
  }, true);
});
document.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
  document.querySelectorAll("div.iframe").forEach(function(div) {
    div.classList.remove("scrollable");
  });
}, true);
div.iframe {
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

div.iframe * {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
}

div.iframe div {
  background-color: rgba(250, 250, 250, 0.5);
}

div.iframe.scrollable div {
  height: 0;
}
Page content
<div class="iframe">
  <iframe src="first frame"></iframe>
  <div></div>
</div>
More page content
<div class="iframe">
  <iframe src="second frame"></iframe>
  <div></div>
</div>




I'm suggesting you some different approaches:
1. Overlay a Transparent Div:
Position a transparent div over the iframe. This div will capture mouse events, allowing scrolling on the parent page while still allowing clicks within the iframe.
Here’s an example of how you can do this using CSS:
<style>
  .iframe-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    pointer-events: none; 
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); 
  }
</style>
<div class="iframe-overlay"></div>
<iframe src="your-iframe-source"></iframe>

Adjust the .iframe-overlay class as needed to fit your specific layout.

Set overflow: hidden for the Body in the Iframe (not listing it in mine as someone already suggested this one.)

2. JavaScript Event Handling:
Use JavaScript to handle mouse events and control scrolling behavior.
When the mouse enters the iframe, disable scrolling on the parent page. When the mouse leaves the iframe, re-enable scrolling.
$(document).ready(function () {
  const iframe = document.getElementById('your-iframe-id');
  const parentBody = document.body;

  iframe.addEventListener('mouseenter', () => {
    parentBody.style.overflow = 'hidden';
  });

  iframe.addEventListener('mouseleave', () => {
    parentBody.style.overflow = 'auto';
  });
});


That looks like very promising, I will give it a try tonight
